# Not able to copy files between ubuntu machines using scp

Tags: linux, ubuntu

when i copy a file from one machine to another (both are ubuntu 16.04) the following error will be shown.
But i ping the machines it will connect each other.
root@192.168.1.114's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.1.114's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.1.114's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).

i disables the firewall of both. But no change .Please advise.

Comment: You need to use the correct password.

Comment: not the issue of the password. I used the root password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the root password is not set by default, are you sure you have set the root password ? cause

```
Permission denied
```

seems to be the issue of the password, maybe you need to double check it ? See if you can successfully switch to root using

```
su -
```

on the destination machine. If not, just set the root passwd by

```
sudo passwd root
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to copy your files to the location only superuser can write? Generally you should use regular user account for logging in and use sudo for administration level tasks.